# How to load zeroes at the begining of values in Python Pandas? nothing works

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

in csv file I have table like below:

```
**col1**
001
023
234
```

And when I try to read csv in pandas I have this table in pandas like:

```
**col1**
1
23
234
```

I tried to:

```
dtype_dic= {"col1": str}
df = pd.read_csv("df.csv", dtype = dtype_dic)
```

and after that some rows are loaded correctly, but there are many rows that still do not have 0's loaded at the beginning (looks like below), how is this possible and what can I do about it ?

```
**col1**

001
23.000
234
```

Comment: I tried running your code as above with the file as I understood it and everything worked fine for me. Try opening your file in Notepad and see if you notice anything about the data leading to why you are seeing the formatting issues.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to show the output you are getting for `print(df)`   Your example worked fine for me too.